# Documenting variables with Doxygen in C

Tags: objective-c, c, doxygen

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * \var int iOne
 * \brief Integer 1
 */
/*
 * \var int iTwo
 * \brief Integer 2
 */
/*
 * \var int iThree
 * \brief Integer 3
 */

/**
 * \brief Imitates a sheep.
 */
void sheep();

/**
 * \brief Main function for test code
 */
int main() {
    int iOne, iTwo, iThree;
    iOne = 1;
    iTwo = 2;
    iThree = 3;
    printf("%d %d %d", iOne, iTwo, iThree);

    return 0;
}

void sheep() {
    printf("Meeeh");
}
```

This doesn't generate descriptions for `iOne`, `iTwo` and `iThree` although that was my intention. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to open your comments as Doxygen comments with `/**`.

It may be clearer to do this, though:

```
int main() {
   /** \brief Integer 1 */
   int iOne;
   /** \brief Integer 2 */
   int iTwo;
   /** \brief Integer 3 */
   int iThree;
   /** ... and so on ... */
}
```

This way you can change the name of the variable without breaking your documentation and it's also easier on other programmers who need to read your source code because the description of the variable is located next to it, not somewhere else in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You're right about your code making more sense, but I want to know how to do the \var definition correctly inside my code. What would be the right way to do that?

Comment: Pieter: First of all, I think you need to document the file itself (`/** @file */ `) and then as I said in my answer, I don't think Doxygen can document local variables.

Comment: I don't think this will work, since they are local variables. You should improve this answer, as for now its misleading.

Answer (score 22):

DOxygen was made to document classes and function headers or, in other words, the **interface**. Think of the documentation as something that other programmers study in order to use your classes and functions properly. You shouldn't use DOxygen to document your implementation. Instead, document your local variables in the source with `//` or `/*  */`.

There are a number of ways to make comments in DOxygen, some examples of which (for member variables) can be seen in the manual [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html). I've copied them below.

```
int var; /*!< Detailed description after the member */

int var; /**< Detailed description after the member */

int var; //!< Detailed description after the member
         //!< 

int var; ///< Detailed description after the member
         ///< 

int var; //!< Brief description after the member

int var; ///< Brief description after the member
```

Comment: I find it a bit confusing that you first explain Doxygen shouldn't be used for this but then show the full support Doxygen gives for documenting it. Do you have any source that states Doxygen was meant to document "the interface" but not the rest?

Comment: The snippet I provide shows ways to document variables which are members of "file, struct, union, class, or enum". Since OP's `iOne, iTwo, iThree` variables are internal to `main()` they are not accessible at any interface-level scope and, therefore, will not be documented by Doxygen. Put a different way: Doxygen doesn't, and shouldn't, generate documentation explaining what the variable `i` does in the statement `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` because the scope of `i` is too limited for that to make sense.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks!